# Attribute Error when Running Django Rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a simple project called **djangowallet** and inside that project, I have created an app called **wallet** with a model **wallet** and just one field called **raddress**.

I have created the serializer, views and URLs and when I runserver it gives the following error.

```
PS C:\Users\Ahmed\djangowallet> python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 448, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 634, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 627, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\djangowallet\djangowallet\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('wallet/', include('wallet.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementInclude.py", line 128, in include
    _include(elem, loader, base_url, max_depth, set())
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\xml\etree\ElementInclude.py", line 136, in _include
    if e.tag == XINCLUDE_INCLUDE:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

This is my URL file in the project directory.

```
from xml.etree.ElementInclude import include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('wallet/', include('wallet.urls'))
]
```

This is the URL file in the wallet app

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'wallet', views.WalletViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking to use [**`include`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#include) so just change:

```
from xml.etree.ElementInclude import include
```

to:

```
from django.urls import include
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it resolved error and got the API root on 127.0.0.8000 but after clicking the root it gives the following error `The '`fields`' option must be a list or tuple or "__all__". Got str.`

`TypeError at /wallet/`

Comment: That seems to be a separate issue. Might be better to ask a separate question for it with the whole stack trace and the relevant code included

Comment: Thanks Brian, check this out as well

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246440/improperly-configured-at-error-in-django-rest-framework?noredirect=1#comment125936535_71246440