# Improperly configured at . error in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

When I access the base URL of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` I get the following error

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "wallet-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

When I try to access the admin URL it works fine but when I access my data URL which is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/wallets` I get a ***404*** error page not found?

This is my serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Wallet

class WalletSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Wallet
        fields = ('__all__')
```

My views.py file is the following

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from .serializers import WalletSerializer
from .models import Wallet

@api_view(['GET'])
def getData(request):
    queryset = Wallet.objects.all()
    serializer = WalletSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is my Models.py file

```
from django.db import models

class Wallet(models.Model):
    raddress = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.raddress
```

I was using a simple class in my ***views.py*** file instead of 'GET' functions which I am doing now and I was also using routers in my ***urls.py*** file but I removed all that so I could create CRUD functions but I face this problem now

Comment: Can you add the `Wallet` model to your question?

Comment: I have added models.py file

Comment: Why are you using a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`? You need to create an API url pattern named "wallet-detail" that takes a pk parameter and returns a single wallet if you use that serializer class, it adds a field named "url" that returns a link to the detail API for the model and by default uses the view named "<model_lowercase>-detail"

Comment: how do I do that can you refer me somewhere or paste here if possible?

Comment: Try using `serializers.ModelSerializer` instead of `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer`, do you need the links if you don't have the detail APIs?

Comment: Alright that works but IDK what you mean when you say detail API's

Comment: That serializer adds a `url` field https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer, that field renders a link to the object using the the view named `<model_lowercase>-detail` by default https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield. You don't have an API that returns a single wallet (a detail view) so you have nothing for that field to link to

Comment: alright so adding, ModelSerializers is the best practise in your opinion?

Comment: Yes, using `serializers.ModelSerializer` should be fine. If you need to include the link to a detail view you can do it later when you have the API

Comment: Well isn't what I am doing called building the API?

Comment: Or an API is a different thing lol, confused

Answer (score 0):

try using ModelViewSet instead of your own custom view as they do in the tutorial

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Also, you might want to check the HyperlinkedModelSerializer documentation, as they are a bit picky

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/